# Determining in template function the shortest float type that faithfully represents integer type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types

```
template< typename int_type >
bool foo( int_type argument )
{
    float_type value = argument; // float_type must faithfully represent argument.
    ...
}
```

That is, I'd like to derive within the template function the shortest floating point type `float_type` that has at least as many significant digits as the template parameter `int_type`.

`foo<int16>` should use `float`.

`foo<int32>` should use `double`.

`foo<int64>` should use `long double`.

Is this doable without specialization?

Comment: *"Is this doable without specialization?"* - of the function template specifically... or in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this is possible without directly using specializations. You can use `std::conditional` from the standard header `type_traits` to define a type conditionally based on the size of `int_type`:

```
template< typename int_type >
bool foo(int_type argument)
{
    using float_type = std::conditional<sizeof(int_type) <= 4,
                                        std::conditional<sizeof(int_type) == 4, double, float>::type,
                                        long double>::type;
    float_type value = argument; // float_type must faithfully represent argument.
    ...
}
```

Comment: A helper if this is needed more than once: `template<class int_type>
using faithful_float_t = std::conditional_t<sizeof(int_type) <= 4, std::conditional_t<sizeof(int_type) == 4, double, float>, long double>;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo The tags mentioned C++11. I agree that your snippet is helpful, if you can rely on C++14 features being present.

Comment: Oups, I missed the C++11 tag. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found that a dummy function signature is the simplest way to map one type to another.  Just overload the function with the input types, and those function result types are the output.  E.g.

```
float fff (int16_t);
double fff (int32_t);

using type = decltype(fff(declval<T>()));
```

Comment: Very clever! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind specialization for looking the value up, you could generate a lookup table to map integer type to floating point type explicitly, like:

```
template <typename T>
struct IntToFloatHelper;
template <>
struct IntToFloatHelper<int16_t> {
    using type = float;
};
template <>
struct IntToFloatHelper<int32_t> {
    using type = double;
};
template <>
struct IntToFloatHelper<int64_t> {
    using type = long double;
};

// then down in the function...
typename IntToFloatHelper<int_type>::type value = argument;
```

This works if you're able to enumerate all possible mappings that you want to support. If the type isn't implemented then you'd get a "implicit instantiation of undefined template" error.

After I wrote this I noticed you mentioned "without specialization" so maybe you already were thinking this was a possible way of going about it but were looking for something different.

Comment: I feel like we can combine this with `std::numeric_limits<>::digits` to come up with thresholds (thereby supporting all types that are supported by numeric limits).